# Disabling autoscaling when the text inside gets bigger than the object in Dia (diagrams editor)?

Tags: graphics

When the text gets longer than, for instance, a circle.
It just scales the circle. Is there any way to make the text go to the next line?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. You'll have to keep pressing *Enter*.